# Traceback Information Lost in Decorator

Tags: python, decorator, traceback

When running the following code I am unable to get the expected line number from the traceback information I extracted from `sys.exc_info()` inside a decorator.

```
import sys


def get_traceback(function):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            function(*args, **kwargs) # line 7
        except:
            return sys.exc_info()[2]
    return wrapper


def inner():
    raise ValueError() # line 14 <--- the expected line number


@get_traceback
def outer():
    inner() # line 19


tb = outer()
print(tb.tb_lineno) # prints 7
print(tb.tb_next.tb_lineno) # prints 19
```

When a similar call to `sys.exc_info()` outside of a decorator I am able to get the appropriate line number. What is the cause of this, and what can I do to get the correct line number?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decorator just adds another step to your traceback.

Here is how you can get it with [traceback](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.extract_tb) built-in library:

```
import traceback

tb = outer()

traceback.extract_tb(tb)[-1].lineno
```

or in previous style, add another *tb_next*:

```
print(tb.tb_next.tb_next.tb_lineno)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [traceback shows up until decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527819/traceback-shows-up-until-decorator)

I tried that into my decorator and it works fine for printing the whole inner and outter stack.